# Drawing an arc, depending on the input time

Tags: javascript, php, css, gd

I need to draw a part of the circle, depending on the input time. For example, from **6:00 to 9:00**, the site of the circle is:

[image]

Blue area I need draws. Accordingly, from 00:10 to 3:20 schedule part of the circle will be elsewhere.

I thought I'd use the **GD** library, but I do not know how (Maybe the question here with geometry and with **sin** and **cos**. Thank you.

**P.S.** I do not know if there is a way to do it via **JavaScript** and/or **CSS**.

Comment: What exactly I can use there for this task?

Comment: what do you mean by input time? is it the time when user is waiting for response(loading time)?

Comment: no, it is some input value, example for: 00:00 to 03:00.

Answer (score 1):

That's the most important bit to solve this problem:

```
x = r * Math.cos(t) + offsetX;
y = r * Math.sin(t) + offsetY;
```

which is parametric form of circle equation... "r" is radius and "t" is 'progress' from 0 to 2π, ([wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle)

You can easily do that in JavaScript using either "canvas" or SVG (check Raphael.js library)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great link :)

[arc](http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/BHEwo)

I hope it works for you :)